# \eqref to give reference to a sequence of subequations

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, subequations

Suppose I have the following code

```
\begin{subequations} 
\begin{align}
a+b = c \label{eq.1}\\ 
d+e = f \label{eq.2}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

I want now that upon giving the reference, it should appear as `(1a-b)`.
`\eqref{eq.1}` and `\eqref{eq.2}` will give output as `1a and 1b` not what I want, which is `(1a-b)`.

Comment: Is this a convention you need to observe? Because it goes very much against the customs of scientific publications, AFAIK, and makes the document very hard to read.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it's a very good idea. However, this is how you can do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globallabel}[1]{%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\theparentequation a--\alph{equation}}\label{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a+b = c \label{eq.1}\\
d+e = f \label{eq.2}
\end{align}
\globallabel{eq}
\end{subequations}

\eqref{eq}

\end{document}
```

The `\eqref` command will print

> (1a-b)