# Equation cross references problem

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering

I'm using the code below to get my equations numbered as (1a), (1b), (1c), (1d) and (1e).

```
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    a+b=c\label{eq1a}\\
    b+c=d\label{eq1b}\\
    c+d=e\label{eq1c}\\
    d+e=f\label{eq1d}\\
    e+f=g\label{eq1e}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

If I use the `\ref{}` command, I'm getting the output as

1a–1e

But, I need to get the final output as mentioned below

1a–e

I have tried many ways, but I can't get the required output. Any suggestion?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68569/eqref-to-give-reference-to-a-sequence-of-subequations